# Interpolation differences on polar contour plots in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to generate contour plots on a polar plot and did some quick scripting in matlab to get some results. Out of curiosity I also wanted to try out the same thing in python using the matplotlib but somehow I am seeing different sets of contour plots for the same input data. I am trying to figure out whats going on and if there is anything I could tweak in my python code to get similar results in both cases.

A screenshot of the matlab results is here:
[image]

In the matlab code I used the `scatteredinterpolant` function to get the interpolated data, I am assuming the differences are occurring due to the interpolation function used?

The input data is  -

```
Angles = [-180, -90, 0 , 90, 180, -135, -45,45, 135, 180,-90, 0, 90, 180 ]

Radii = [0,0.33,0.33,0.33,0.33,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.6,0.6,0.6,0.6]

Values = [30.42,24.75, 32.23, 34.26, 26.31, 20.58, 23.38, 34.15,27.21, 22.609, 16.013, 22.75, 27.062, 18.27]
```

This was done using python 2.7, on spyder. I have tried both `scipy.interpolate.griddata` as well as `matplotlib.mlab.griddata` and the results are similar. I was unable to get the `nn` method working in `mlab.griddata` because it kept giving me masked data.

Apologies if I am missing anything relevant - please let me know if anyother info is required I will update my post.

Edit:

The linear scipt griddata image looks like:
[image]

And the cubic scipy image looks like
[image]

As for the code, here is the code - I pass the interpolation type string into the function where this code is present. So 'linear' and 'cubic' are the 2 inputs.

```
val = np.array(list(values[i]))
radius = np.array(list(gamma[i]))    
ang = [math.radians(np.array(list(theta[i]))[x]) for x in xrange(0,len(theta[i]))]
radiiGrid = np.linspace(min(radius),max(radius),100)
anglesGrid = np.linspace(min(ang),max(ang),100)
radiiGrid, anglesGrid = np.meshgrid(radiiGrid, anglesGrid)
zgrid = griddata((ang,radius),val,(anglesGrid,radiiGrid), method=interpType)
```

The angle input is what comes out of `np.array(list(theta[i]))[x]` - this is because the angle information is stored in a list of tuples (this is because I am reading in and sorting data). I took a look at the code to make sure the data is correct and it seems to line up. gamma corresponds to radii and values are the values in the sample data I provided. 
Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you provide an image of the python contours, so we know how the two methods differ?

Comment: What matplotlib code and what image did that make?  We need to see the differences you're seeing, not just one image.

Comment: updated the original post with the relevant info. I am not sure how I managed to not include other plots as they are all at the same imgur link. But those are all updated now.

Comment: @tom Thanks for fixing the post. I couldnt figure out how to do inline images.. will keep it in mind next time.

Comment: Its just a matter of needing more rep :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Polar plots in `matplotlib` can get tricky. When that happens, a quick solution is to convert radii and angle to x,y,  plot in a normal projection. Then make a empty polar axis to superimpose on it:

```
from scipy.interpolate import griddata


Angles = [-180, -90, 0 , 90, 180, -135, 
          -45,45, 135, 180,-90, 0, 90, 180 ]

Radii = [0,0.33,0.33,0.33,0.33,0.5,0.5,
         0.5,0.5,0.5,0.6,0.6,0.6,0.6]

Angles = np.array(Angles)/180.*np.pi
x = np.array(Radii)*np.sin(Angles)
y = np.array(Radii)*np.cos(Angles)

Values = [30.42,24.75, 32.23, 34.26, 26.31, 20.58, 
          23.38, 34.15,27.21, 22.609, 16.013, 22.75, 27.062, 18.27]

Xi = np.linspace(-1,1,100)
Yi = np.linspace(-1,1,100)

#make the axes
f = plt.figure()
left, bottom, width, height= [0,0, 1, 0.7]
ax  = plt.axes([left, bottom, width, height])
pax = plt.axes([left, bottom, width, height], 
                projection='polar',
                axisbg='none')
cax = plt.axes([0.8, 0, 0.05, 1])
ax.set_aspect(1)
ax.axis('Off')


# grid the data.
Vi = griddata((x, y), Values, (Xi[None,:], Yi[:,None]), method='cubic')
cf = ax.contour(Xi,Yi,Vi, 15, cmap=plt.cm.jet)

#make a custom colorbar, because the default is ugly
gradient = np.linspace(1, 0, 256)
gradient = np.vstack((gradient, gradient))
cax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
cax.yaxis.tick_right()
cax.imshow(gradient.T, aspect='auto', cmap=plt.cm.jet)
cax.set_yticks(np.linspace(0,256,len(cf1.get_array())))
cax.set_yticklabels(map(str, cf.get_array())[::-1])
```

[image]

Comment: This is awesome. I know effectively this is what MATLAB does as well. I wasnt sure how to replicate that here. This looks much better than what I already had. Thank you!

Comment: Quick question though - why set ax.set_aspect(1) if thats going to be turned off anyway?

Comment: `ax.axis('Off')` turn the display off (x, y, grid, box etc), `ax` itself is not going away.  You can leave it `'on'` to make sure the superimposing polar plot aligns well.  Then turn it off, otherwise it looks busy.

Comment: One of these days I am going to do a big clean up of the polar plotting methods in `Maplotlib`.  Maybe after I quit my job or get layoff.

Comment: This post was helpful, but it appears some things have changed in ```Matplotlib```. Instead of ```axisbg``` in ```plt.axes``` use ```facecolor```. And if you are using python3, you should change ```map(...)``` to ```list(map(...))```. There might be a more elegant solution for that, but this works. Also near the end I believe ```cf1.get_array()``` should be ```cf.get_array()```.